# Wrong theme as other user role

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

When I am loged in, I have the Seven admin-theme, as administrator. But when I have created an new user with a new role, named "editor". This users theme is a mix with Seven and Zen theme. How is that possible? Under apperence tab the admininstrator-theme is Seven - but it's showing as Seven/Zen-mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a permission to view pages in the admin theme. Make sure it is checked for the appropriate roles.
Second, by default only paths starting with /admin/ will be shown in the admin theme. A page like /node/add/story may still be displayed in the front end theme. If you need more control, check out http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme.

Comment: YES! Thank you. Now I got it! I didn't find it before because I wrote "tema" (theme in swedish) in the searchbox in my firefox but that couldn't find it because the word admin theme is one word in swedish - "administrationstema". Strange!